# Komma bei zweifacher Kausalität

Tags: comma

Im Satz

> Weil heute Sonntag ist, muss ich nicht arbeiten und kann deshalb länger schlafen.

ist die Kommasetzung klar. Was ist aber, wenn man diesen Satz umformuliert? Ist im Satz

> Weil heute Sonntag ist, muss ich nicht arbeiten(,) und deshalb kann ich länger schlafen.

an der gekennzeichneten Stelle ein Komma notwendig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wenn der Teilsatz nach dem Beistrich auch alleine für sich stehen könnte und so immer noch Sinn macht, dann *kann* man (muss aber nicht) vor dem *und* einen Beistrich setzen. D.h. es geht darum, ob es sich um einen reinen Nebensatz handelt der nach dem und kommt oder nicht.

Nachdem

> Deshalb kann ich länger schlafen

auch alleine stehend einen Hauptsatz bilden kann, darf in deinem Beispiel ein Beistrich vor dem **und** stehen (muss aber nicht).

Wäre dein Satz

> Weil heute Sonntag ist, muss ich nicht arbeiten und auch sonst nichts tun.

Nachdem *Auch sonst nichts tun.* selbständig keinen Hauptsatz bilden kann, wäre also der *Beistrich vor dem **und** hier nicht erlaubt*.

Ähnlich verhält es sich übrigens auch mit oder und sowie, die Regeln dazu werden auf dieser Seite sehr gut erklärt:
https://schreibenundleben.com/zeichensetzung-leicht-gemacht-1-komma-vor-und-komma-vor-sowie-und-andere-schicke-kommaregeln/

Comment: Warum wäre "Deshalb kann ich länger schlafen." alleine nicht sinnvoll? Man könnte den Satz "Weil heute Sonntag ist, muss ich nicht arbeiten und deshalb kann ich länger schlafen." doch in zwei Sätze aufteilen, um "Weil heute Sonntag ist, muss ich nicht arbeiten. Deshalb kann ich länger schlafen." zu erhalten.

Comment: Guter Einwand! Die Regel, die ich erklärt habe stimmt zwar, aber in deinem konkreten Beispiel ist es umgekehrt. "Deshalb kann ich länger schlafen" macht so betrachtet doch alleine Sinn. Deswegen darf ein Beistrich vor dem "und" stehen. Ich habe meine Antwort entsprechend angepasst und ein eindeutiges anderes Beispiel angeführt, bei dem vor dem "und" KEIN Beistrich stehen darf.